# center a big image in smaller div

Tags: html, css

My goal is to center an image which is bigger in a my div.
I do not want to resize the image.
The center of the image must be displayed.

My div is defined like:

```
div.thumbnail 
{
   display: block;
   margin: auto;
   height: 100px;
   width: 100px;
   overflow: hidden;
}
```

And then my idea was to create this additionally for the image:

```
div.thumbnail img 
{
   overflow: hidden;
   margin: auto;
}
```

The HTML looks like:

```
<div class="thumbnail">
    <a href="{{ url_for('showphotos') }}?key={{ album['AlbumName'] }}">
        <img src="{{ url_for ('static', filename=album['ThumbPath']) }}">
    </a>
</div>
```

But this does not work for me. 
Any advice how to fix this?

Thanks Darrell.

Comment: If you could provide a fiddle of the issue it would be easier to understand what you're asking for.

Comment: You say it's not working for you - what behavior are you seeing?

Comment: you can take overflow hidden off of the image. Set it to display block and give it say, margin:-20% 0 0 -20%; If you want to center it perfectly I think you will need some js... or if you know your images will all be the same then just give them a specific negative margin. I usually just use -20% when I want to achieve this effect.

Edit: I guess you would want to do this to the <a> not the img. missed that.

Comment: Will the images be a certain definite size?

Comment: AJak, I want to create thumbnails of images which vary in size. The image can be portrait or landscaped. If I resize the image is always looks akward and to compressed.

Comment: user1618143, I mean, I don't get the result I want.

Comment: The images can be portrait or landscaped. the size may vary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the trick. It is easy to center the image horizontally. However the vertical centering is not so easy and involves more markup. You may use *background-position* property. Here is jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/krasimir/ydzZN/2/

HTML

```
<div class="thumbnail">
    <a href="#" style="background-image: url('http://www.australia.com/contentimages/about-landscapes-nature.jpg')">
    </a>
</div>
```

CSS

```
div.thumbnail {
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
div.thumbnail a {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-position: center center;
}
```

There is a bad effect of course. Your image will not be indexed, because it is in a css style.

Comment: That's a really **bad** practice. If you're going to use `background-image`, set the background image property on `<a>` element. [`src` attribute is obligatory for `<img>` element](http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/html3/img.html)

Comment: Also, you forgot to add `position: relative` to `.thumbnail`. Without it, the image will stretch all the way across the page. It won't display wrong in this case, but it's one of those things that can screw you up.

Answer (score 1):

Horizontally centering the image should be straightforward, but vertically centering page elements is a pain. A cleaner solution would be to set the image as the `background-image` of the div (or possibly the anchor tag) and use the other css background properties to position it. Something like: `style="background-image: url([url]); background-position: center"` should do the job.

Answer (score 1):

This is by far the easiest solution I know, you need two divs to do what you are trying to do. like so:

```
   <div class="thumbnail">
      <div class="image-container">
        <a href="{{ url_for('showphotos') }}?key={{ album['AlbumName'] }}">
            <img src="{{ url_for ('static', filename=album['ThumbPath']) }}">
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
```

css

```
   .thumbnail{
     width: 100px;
     height:100px;
     overflow:hidden;
   }
   .image-container{
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
     //use the margin property to position the image in the div.
     margin: 0 0 0 0;
   }
```

we set the thumbnail div to whatever size we want and by making the overflow hidden the div inside thumbnail, in this case our image will be full size but cropped to what ever spot of the image we wish to show .

Comment: Be aware: This won't work well if the images are not a consistent size.

Answer (score 1):

To center multiple sizes of images inside of a single sized `div`, set the image as the background (centered) of the `div` in CSS - no `img` elements necessary. Then set a fixed width for the div and hide the overflow.

```
<div class="s1"> [ Content ] </div>
<div class="s2"> [ Content ] </div>
<div class="s3"> [ Content ] </div>

div{
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.s1{
    background:transparent url("http://placehold.it/500x500") center center no-repeat;
}
.s2{
    background:transparent url("http://placehold.it/700x500") center center no-repeat;
}
.s3{
    background:transparent url("http://placehold.it/500x700") center center no-repeat;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/daCrosby/sYgHG/1/